# enum object's comparision doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, module

File structure is:

```
├── module
│   ├── script1.py
│   ├── enums.py
├── script2.py
```

enums.py:

```
from enum import Enum, auto
        
class Color(Enum):
    RED = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
```

script1.py:

```
from enums import Color

blue = Color.BLUE
```

script2.py:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./module')

from module.enums import Color
from module.script1 import blue

assert blue.name == Color.BLUE.name # true
assert blue.value == Color.BLUE.value # true
assert blue == Color.BLUE  # false
```

Run script2.py, get exception:

```
  File "/Users/python/script2.py", line 9, in <module>
    assert blue == Color.BLUE  # false
AssertionError
```

Why the third assertion is not true? how to make it true?

Comment: Short answer: don't mess with `sys.path` -- by importing the module via a different name, you get a copy of that module, not the original; so everything in that copy will fail `is` tests, and the case of `Enum`, even equality tests can fail.

Comment: @EthanFurman Interesting! Thanks for you response

Comment: @EthanFurman Can I ask a follow-up question?  What if `module` is written by others and I just want to use it in my project by copy-pasting it into my project folder without changing his code. When he writes the module, since his `pythonPath` contains `module` folder so `from enums import Color` works. But what can I do instead of `sys.path.append` the `module` folder?

Comment: You'll need to make that an actual question -- answering in a comment would not be easy, nor useful for others.  Feel free to post the link here.

Comment: @EthanFurman Here it is! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64812916/how-to-use-others-code-as-a-module-in-my-project