# how to use other's code as a module in my project?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

File structure is:

```
├── module
│   ├── script1.py
│   ├── enums.py
├── script2.py
```

enums.py:

```
from enum import Enum, auto
        
class Color(Enum):
    RED = auto()
    BLUE = auto()
```

script1.py:

```
from enums import Color

blue = Color.BLUE
```

script2.py:

```
from module.enums import Color
from module.script1 import blue

assert blue.name == Color.BLUE.name
assert blue.value == Color.BLUE.value
assert blue == Color.BLUE
```

Run script2.py, get exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/python/py_helloworld/script2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from module.script1 import blue
  File "/Users/python/py_helloworld/module/script1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from enums import Color
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enums'
```

What if `module` is written by others and I just want to use it in my project by copy-pasting it into my project folder without changing his code. When he wrote the module, since his pythonPath contains module folder so `from enums import Color` works. But what can I do instead of `sys.path.append` the module folder?

PS:

- I can't sys.path.append('./module') because `assert blue == Color.BLUE` will be false

Comment: Maybe this is an error due to a circular import. [Have a look over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python)

Comment: Are you sure that both the parent directory and `module` contain a file named `__init__.py`?

Comment: @statist32 I think if it's circular import, an ImportError will be raised instead of ModuleNotFoundError.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy No `__init__.py` in my case. I'm running on python3.8 so I don't think `__init__.py` need to be explicitly created.

Comment: If `module` was written not as a package, such that the fully qualified name of `enums` is just that, it’s questionable at **best** to pretend that it was written as a package named `module` instead.  Relative imports can sometimes make code “portable” in this sense, but they can’t hide the difference between “package” and “not”, since Python doesn’t have a notion of a global package.

Comment: @DavisHerring Are you saying that in order for others to use your code as a package, the package author needs to do everything in relative import?

Comment: @xyshell: I’m saying that doing so somewhat increases the chance of being able to copy one project’s files into a subdirectory of another.  That doesn’t make that practice **advisable**!  The only real answer is to install packages, not copy them like NPM does.

Comment: @DavisHerring Interesting!